# Using jQuery to pop up dropdown menu after change event happen in another

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have 2 drop down menu and I would like to make it so that when someone select in one drop down menu then another drop down menu should automatically pop up so that user need to click to open up second one.

```
<select id="dropdwon1">
 <option value="1">Item1</option>
 <option value="2">Item2</option>
 <option value="3">Item3</option>
</select>

<select id="dropdwon2">
 <option value="1">Item1</option>
 <option value="2">Item2</option>
 <option value="3">Item3</option>
</select>
```

jquery is

```
$("#dropdwon1").change(function(){
            $( "#dropdwon2" ).focus();
            $( "#dropdwon2" ).click();
});
```

I have putted this code snap in jsfiddle also.
https://jsfiddle.net/nandkumar90/z0bc2wyt/

expected result after selection made on first drop down menu 
[image]
Can someone guide to achieve expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle with working code, Please follow https://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/z0bc2wyt/1/

```
var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
e.initMouseEvent('mousedown');
$("#dropdwon2")[0].dispatchEvent(e);
```

Comment: I was trying to open dropdown menu after selection made on date by apply same changes on  text field.**<input id="datetimepicker" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Check In" style="margin-left:-2px;"/>** but its not working ?  can u suggest some solution ?]

Comment: Use that dispatch event function in above answer at onselect event of calendar. I'll share a fiddle after some time

Comment: @Nand see the fiddle for dropdown opening by calendar  select http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/8w8v9/433/

Comment: Yes it worked. Manish! We (http://stayuncle.com/home) are looking for front end developer. Let me know if u r interested.